# Unable to access a URL that I can see is live from a proxy

Tags: http, curl, networking

I'm trying to install Homebrew on my Mac. When I run, the install script, I get:

```
$ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Operation timed out
```

However, I can see from proxies that https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install is live. It won't load for me in Chrome either, so I can tell the problem is at my end.

I'm on a home network, so no proxies applicable.

When I ping raw.githubusercontent.com locally, I get:

```
PING raw.githubusercontent.com (90.207.238.183): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 90.207.238.183: icmp_seq=0 ttl=252 time=13.273 ms
64 bytes from 90.207.238.183: icmp_seq=1 ttl=252 time=10.497 ms
```

How can I figure out what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out that Sky (my webhost) were blocking github as a fraudulent site. Unblocking via Sky Broadband Shield fixed the issue.

http://helpforum.sky.com/t5/Broadband/githubusercontent-com-blocked-by-Sky-Broadband-Shield/td-p/2722951